why can't load value from a global variable straight to a register?
hello i'm trying to access a global variable declared and already assigned a value to in C file, I made a simple C program that has a global variable "NUM" and calls exitprocnow, the exitprocnow pass the NUM variable to the win32 API ExitProcess to exit the program with the value of NUM,
main.c:
int NUM;

extern void exitprocnow();

int main(void) {
    NUM = 10;
    exitprocnow();
    return 1;
}

exitprocnow.asm
[bits 64]
extern NUM
extern ExitProcess

section .text
    global exitprocnow

exitprocnow:
    mov rcx, [NUM]
    call ExitProcess

but i get the following error when compiling the file:
$> nasm -f win64 .\exitproc.asm -o call.o
$> gcc .\main.c .\call.o -lkernel32
.\call.o:.\exitproc.asm:(.text+0x4): relocation truncated to fit: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_ADDR32 against symbol "NUM" defined in .bss section in C:\Users\YO\AppData\Local\Temp\cccoJTdm.o
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

however when i move the address of NUM to a separate register like rdx then load value that the address at rdx point to it works fine.
exitprocnow:
    mov rdx, NUM
    mov rcx, [rdx]
    call ExitProcess

i just wanna know why i can't just load data straight to a register? and my second question (sorry for asking off topic question) what does that error i got at first means?

Use mov rcx, [rel NUM] or put default rel at the top of your asm file. The effective address only allows 32 bit displacement but the mov rdx, NUM can take the full 64 bits of the address.
